# Half responsive css layout (depends on rest of width and height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

Hello I need an advice from you. I have 3 divs - one with absolute size X and Y, and I want 2 others to be depends of rest of window width and height.
I want achieve sticked elements too (`margins`, or `padding` 0?)

I'm doing this now ith jquery and setwidth, setheight, but this doesn't give good effects.

```
$("#console").height(window.innerHeight - gameCanvas.height - 19);
$("#menu").height(gameCanvas.height);
$("#menu").width(window.innerWidth - gameCanvas.width - 6);
```

Sorry but I'm new in CSS and cant search good answer for my question

#menu is right up element

#console is down element

#gameCanvas is up left element

Please help me, how can I achieve it?
Can I achieve it only with css?

Comment: Yes you can achieve it with only CSS. A good starting point is [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks i will read this, but for my noob project better answer is below. I will use grid, when i will have more elements and complexivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can very likely be done with CSS alone. See if this works for you:

```
#gameCanvas{
  width:1024px;
  height:512px;
  float:left;
}
#menu{
  height:512px;
}
#console{
  clear:both;
  height:calc(100vh - 512px);
}
```

I used `calc` and `vh` to set the height of `#console`. That part might have to be done with javascript to ensure an excellent browser support. The above code [should work](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=vh) in [90% of the browsers](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=calc).

Comment: Thank you very much! So this is better answer cause it's very simple like my project :D Thanks one again